# Why does C# split give me an array ending in an empty line?

Tags: c#

I have the following expression:

```
"<p>What ?</p>\n<pre>Starting Mini</pre>"
```

When I perform a split as follows:

```
   var split = content
      .Split(new[] { "<pre>", "</pre>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then it gives me three entries:

```
"<p>What ?</p>\n"
"Starting Mini"
""
```

Why does it give an empty line as the third entry and how can I avoid this?

Comment: You can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` intead of `StringSplitOptions.None` to remove it;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "why" is simply: the input (if you don't remove empty entries) will always "split" at any occurrence of the separator(s), so if the separator(s) appear `n` times in the string, then the array will be `n+1` long. In particular, this essentially lets you know *where* they occurred in the original string (although when using multiple separators, it doesn't let you know which appeared where).

For example, with a simple example (csv without any escaping etc):

```
string[] arr = input.Split(','); // even if something like "a,b,c,d,"
// which allows...
int numberOfCommas = arr.Length - 1;
string original = string.Join(",", arr);
```

The fix is, as already mentioned, to use `RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead to remove empty string in list

```
 var split = content
  .Split(new[] { "<pre>", "</pre>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: OP asks (also) for the reason of the empty string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: thanks for comment, just the way of `Split`, method works

Answer (score 2):

You get this behaviour as specified from Microsoft:
[*"Adjacent delimiters yield an array element that contains an empty string ("")."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx)
So since you have the last pre you get the last empty array element

Answer (score 1):

The **reason** you are getting this behaviour is that your one of the delimeter `</pre>` happens to exist at the **end of the string**.

You may see: [string.Split - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

> ...**a delimiter is found at the beginning or end** of this instance, the
>   corresponding array element contains Empty

To overcome this:

Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead of `StringSplitOptions.None`

[StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx)

> The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty
>   string

```
 var split = content
       .Split(new[] { "<pre>", "</pre>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mailou, instead of giving 'StringSplitOptions.None' try 'StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries'. It removes the the empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the

```
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries enumerator.
```

Answer (score 0):

The split string[] values not include any empty string by using **StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries**

```
var split = content
  .Split(new[] { "<pre>", "</pre>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Reference: [StringSplitOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty line due to

> `</pre>`

You are instructing `split` function to split by `<pre>` and `</pre>`

As result with `<pre>` you are getting

```
<p>What ?</p>\n
Starting Mini</pre>
```

And next result is with `</pre>` is

```
<p>What ?</p>\n
Starting Mini
...
```