# Adding numbers from list of custom delimieters

Tags: c#

I am writing program to add numbers from string which will be seperated from delimeters

```
  private static readonly char[] Separators = { ',', '\n', '/','@'  };

public int Add(string numbers)
{
    if (numbers.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return numbers.Split(Separators).Select(int.Parse).Sum();
}
```

When i pass the following string to Add method `//@\n2@3`
Then i get below error **Input string was not in a correct format.**

I expect answer to be 5

Comment: Hint, try to explain why `int.Parse("");` throws the same exception.

Comment: @gunr2171 because you cannot parse empty string

Comment: Awesome. Now, how many array entries will there be from `numbers.Split(Separators)`, and what are the contents of those elements?

Comment: A better solution may be to use regex to get all consecutive digits in a string and parse them as numbers.

Comment: @gunr2171 there will be 6 entries

Comment: Careful when comparing a string to empty... numbers.Equals(string.Empty). Consider using String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numbers) instead. Currently calling Add() with " " and null will give you errors.

Comment: @AnthonyG. do you have answer to my question? I will change code to use String.IsnullorEmpty

Comment: @James what take a look at the overloads for `String.Split`, particularly [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-stringsplitoptions)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does C# split give me an array ending in an empty line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776916/why-does-c-sharp-split-give-me-an-array-ending-in-an-empty-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `string.Split` will create empty groups if two delimiters are right next to each other. For example `"3,,4".Split(',');` will produce an array with three elements ("3", empty string, and "4").

You can change this in one of two ways. The first (and probably simpler) is to have the Split ignore empty entries.

```
numbers.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Or you can use `Where` in Linq

```
numbers.Split(Separators).Where(x => x.Length > 0)
```

This will prevent elements with a **blank** string value reaching `int.Parse`. Of course, there are still other things you should do to validate your input before attempting to parse, but that's another topic.

Comment: THats awesome. Very nicely explained

Comment: One issue you may run into is you are parsing strings and assuming all values delimited by separators are numeric. If test string was "//@\nf@b" it may have been split, but int.Parse will blow up. To be safe you may want to use numbers.Split(Separators).Where(x=> Int32.TryParse(x, out int _)).Select(int.Parse).Sum();